# Why does large volt-second product need a large inductance?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductor

This is a buck converter that converts from a high input voltage VIN (60V) to a low output voltage (3V).

I read that because this case has a large voltage-second product we have to use a large inductance.

Can anyone explain the relation? Why is a large inductance needed?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that statement is true. You should probably look for (and give) more context here.

Comment: A Weber is the square-root of the product of the magnetic energy stored, in Joules, and the Henries. For a given amount of magnetic energy to be stored, the Henries will be proportional to the square of the Webers. So more Webers means more Henries, if the magnetic energy storage is the same per cycle. Except that it's not a linear relationship, but a square-root/squared one. So 10 times the Webers requires 100 times the Henries, energy the same. Or, put another way, if you only needed \$10\:\mu\text{H}\$ for a certain Weber value, 10 times that Weber value would require \$1\:\text{mH}\$.

Answer (score 3):

When you apply a constant voltage across an inductor for a short period of time, current ramps up from zero amps to some value. The rate at which the current rises is determined by this well known equation: -

$$\dfrac{di}{dt} = \frac{V}{L}$$

So, if you have more voltage or less inductance, current rises faster. The faster current rises in a given time, the higher are the chances that it may cause core saturation so, re-arranging the above formula, we can put it in terms of volt-seconds: -

$$ di = dt\dfrac{V}{L}$$

So, the value of current can be written as volt-seconds divided by inductance: -

$$I = \text{time}\cdot V / L$$

And, if you operate a certain value inductance with a large voltage for too long, you will get an excessive current that may produce significant core saturation.

This is the reason why switch mode power supplies make use of smaller magnetic components; their operating frequency is so much higher than 50/60 Hz and, despite the current ramp time being so much quicker (due to the inductance being much less), the high operating frequency ensures that the time for current to ramp to a potential saturating level is much, much shorter. In effect, a higher operating frequency means smaller magnetic components.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage difference is relatively large, so the duty cycle D is relatively low, 5%. This is usually too much of a difference to many common buck converters.

Which means that the on time for the S1 must be relatively short in comparison to the converter frequency, and it is hard to drive S1 on for a short period quickly and precisely.

It takes also energy to turn the FET on and off, and the shorter the on period is, the faster you must turn it on to keep the turn-on time and turn-off time relatively short in comparison to the on period.

So the only way to make the S1 on time period reasonable (in regards to turn-on time, turn-off time, and precision required to control the on time) is to lower the converter frequency, and lower frequency means it needs higher inductance so that the inductor does not saturate during the S1 on time and the ripple current stays within typical limits (e.g. 30% of output current) and the output voltage ripple is not too large.